# How to clearly express "A so B" besides "...as many as ten. And so, that there is..."

Tags: clarity

**Preample:** This is a ["How do I express this idea?" question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1401/48332). I hope that it is sufficiently on-topic here. I'm a native English speaker but have no formal understanding of the English language and the folks in English SE seem to smell that and quickly close my questions there. (e.g. didn't do a sufficient amount of research or included the wrong research) so I'm going to try to ask this here instead.

---

Here's part of the original way I wrote a [comment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/help-understanding-the-down-voting-on-these-two-questions-and-the-hopefully-tem?noredirect=1#comment15191_6233):

> Yes I see what you mean and I understand, but of course most SE questions have several answers, a few may have as many as ten, so that there is more than one answer does not mean a question should be primarily opinion-based.

and here's how I quickly edited it:

> Yes I see what you mean and I understand, but of course most SE questions have several answers, a few may have as many as ten. That there is more than one answer does not mean a question should be primarily opinion-based.

My problem is with the "that there is X does not mean Y" getting lost in the first version because (at least when I'm) reading and see the two words "so that" I lump them together and then start reading "there is" as the next group.

I suppose the comma that I've inserted in the first version helps, but is there a better way to preserve the "A so B" logic (where B is "that there is X does not mean Y") than hoping the comma works?

How can this be rephrased to ensure the "A so B" nature is preserved while avoiding the possibility that "so that" presents a potential confusion?

I could perhaps use

> ...as many as ten. And so, that there is...

but to me that looks awkward and overly stylized. It might work in a speech (e.g. "And in conclusion...") but as a short, concise explanation it doesn't seem to fit in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned "so as" and "that..."
Other options to link two sentences include:

- So [even] if
- The fact that
- The presence of

Conjunctions/adverbs could be optionally added at the beginning of the second sentence:

- However
- But

Comment: Thanks! I like these options as they don't add length and complexity yet do help to clear up the potential ambiguity. If I were writing a scientific paper I might choose a different structure altogether, but for this comment I think that "So even if..." works best for me in this case.